# Adequate Regression with independent variable that is only relevant above a threshold?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I am wondering what kind of regression would be well suited to analyze whether the independent variable does only impact the dependent variable if it is above a certain threshold.

Even though this might not be true in reality, let us say that below a certain traffic density there will be no car crashes. Once a certain barrier of traffic density is exceeded, the density impacts the number of car crashes in a (non-)linear way.

Is anybody aware of a reasonable model to analyze such a relationship, especially if we do not know the level of the barrier at which the relationship gets significantly different from zero?

I am kind of thinking towards a regime-switching approach, but I am very uncertain if this approach would be well suited. Would it be well-suited?